# Generate SQL output in a specific format

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two database tables.
For example:

1. User:-

   | User ID | Name |
   | --- | --- |
   | 1 | Mr. A |
   | 2 | Mr. B |
2. Email Details:-

   | Email ID | User ID | Email |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 1 | safk@as.com |
   | 2 | 1 | asdfk@ad.com |
   | 3 | 2 | wqe@sda.com |

I want to generate the result using Oracle SQL query in the following format:-

```
|User ID | Name |  Email1    | Email2     |
| -------|------|------------|------------|
| 1      | Mr. A| safk@as.com|asdfk@ad.com|
| 2      | Mr. B| wqe@sda.com|            |
```

(A user may have any number of emails.)

_________*********************create table statements*********************

```
create table Users(
  UserId int,
  Name varchar2(50)
);

create table emailDetails(
  EmailId int,
  UserId int,
  Email varchar2(50)
  );

insert into Users(UserId, Name) values (1, 'Mr A');
insert into Users(UserId, Name) values (2, 'Mr B');
insert into EmailDetails(EmailId, UserId, Email) values(1,1,'safk@as.com');
insert into EmailDetails(EmailId, UserId, Email) values(2,1,'asdfk@ad.com');
insert into EmailDetails(EmailId, UserId, Email) values(3,2,'wqe@sda.com');
```

Comment: OK, and did you try anything yet, and find any specific problems? SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) From your question, I gather that if a user has more than two emails, you arbitrarily want two in the result set.

Comment: @underscore_d, I have found a solution using listagg function which will put multiple email id in one column. But I want to put each email id in different columns like email1,email2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

if you are allowed to have one column called emails with a comma delimited list then you can use listagg.  if you need a dynamic number of columns you will need to use dynamic sql.

here is the solution with one column called emails

```
SELECT
    u.userId, name,
    LISTAGG(email,', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY u.userId) AS emails
from users u 
join emaildetails e on(u.userId = e.Userid)
GROUP BY u.userId, name
ORDER BY u.userId;
```

you can run the fiddle here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/546eb/8

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function, you can then use that in a subquery in combination with some grouping.

```sql
  SELECT u.userid,
         u.name,
         MIN (CASE WHEN e.email_num = 1 THEN e.email END)     AS email1,
         MIN (CASE WHEN e.email_num = 2 THEN e.email END)     AS email2
    FROM users u
         LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT userid,
                 email,
                 ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY emailid)     AS email_num
            FROM emailDetails) e
             ON (u.userid = e.userid)
GROUP BY u.userid, u.name;
```